# Find two approximate values in one Pandas Series. Create a flag on another based on a criteria

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, series

I'm looking to :

1-  Review all values of one Series (quantity )

2-  Dynamically highlight all that fall within a criteria (abs(1.5) quantity units in this example) with a "flag" in another Series (near).

3 - in case of a True value the flag should display all index values separated by a space or other character

The below DataFrame displays the desired outcome in the near Series.

```
index | quantity |      near
----------------------------------
inv1  |  2017.45 |  no
inv2  |   102.10 |  inv2 inv3 inv6
inv3  |   101.60 |  inv2 inv3 
inv5  |   200.4  |  no
inv6  |   103.39 |  inv2 inv6
```

Any ideas ? Thank you in advance.

Pandas 0.21.1 and Python 3.6.5

Comment: Your flags appear to be incorrect.

Comment: should be inv6, no?

Comment: apologies - I've corrected the flags now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC:

```
q = df.quantity.values
x = df['index']

i, j = np.where(np.abs(np.subtract.outer(q, q)) <= 1.5)

df.assign(near=x.map(x[i].groupby(x[j].values).apply(' '.join)))

  index  quantity            near
0  inv1   2017.45            inv1
1  inv2    102.10  inv2 inv3 inv6
2  inv3    101.60       inv2 inv3
3  inv5    200.40            inv5
4  inv6    103.39       inv2 inv6
```

You can avoid the diagonal comparisons

```
q = df.quantity.values
x = df['index']

m = np.abs(np.subtract.outer(q, q)) <= 1.5
np.fill_diagonal(m, False)
i, j = np.where(m)

df.assign(near=x.map(x[i].groupby(x[j].values).apply(' '.join)).fillna('no'))

  index  quantity       near
0  inv1   2017.45         no
1  inv2    102.10  inv3 inv6
2  inv3    101.60       inv2
3  inv5    200.40         no
4  inv6    103.39       inv2
```

Comment: Thank you! I've applied the first option  and will study the second. Also thanks for your manual on the pandas concat function. Really clicked for me.